# Why is oldfiles not listing last edited file

Tags: save, edit

I use vim in the following way:

I open vim.

1. Then I press `i` to start writing.
2. Then I save the buffer and give the file a name by issuing the command `:w some-file-name.txt`
3. Then I quit vim by `:x`

Then I would expect `some-file-name.txt` to be in the oldfiles list next time I open vim, but when I use `:oldfiles` it is not there.

If I, on the other hand, start my process by using `:e some-file-name.txt` and thereby giving the file a name before I write the content, then the file is actually showing up in the oldfiles list next time I start vim.

But I prefer writing content first and then giving the filename later.

Does anyone know why my preferred workflow does not put my last edited file in oldfiles?

Comment: Btw, I just installed nvim. And in nvim oldfiles does indeed list a file created with my workflow as described in the question.

Comment: the files created in the above mentioned ways do show up in :marks in vim - but not in :oldfiles it seems

Comment: Did you really close vim or was it still open? Did it work after explicitly running `:wviminfo`? Can you reproduce this using `vim --clean`?

Comment: Thanks, Christian.

1) Yes, I closed vim by the command :x (no other buffers open)
2) when saving with :w then doing :wviminfo then :x - upon restart the file is still not in the oldfiles list
3) Yes - I tried 'vim --clean' - but since it also does not load .viminfo this does not work

Comment: I also tried with an empty .vimrc, of course

Comment: Hm, this looks like a bug to me then. What Vim version is this?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I see same problem persists in a quite modern build (8.2.1941). `v:oldfiles` do not get updated, unless the buffer was read from disk at least once (doing extra `:e` between steps (2) and (3) helps).

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt - vim --version gives: VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, kompileret Nov  4 2020 11:27:02)
macOS-version
Rettelser som er med: 1-1950
Kompileret af Homebrew

Comment: Btw, I have the same problem in MacVim, this version: Custom Version 8.2.1719 (166)

Comment: It would be really nice of you to fill in [issue](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/new/choose)

Comment: Thanks, I have done so here: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7348

Comment: I created https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/7350 to fix this

Comment: That was fast. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a vim bug: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/7348

Which Christian Brabandt has opened a PR to fix: https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/7350

It was merged and released in Vim version 8.2.2039.